# HTML/PHP weird error

Tags: php, html, variables, undefined

So i'm working on a website on which you can teach newcommers some codes we need to know.
This is on the site: A table, within a form, where you have to write in the correct code in an input field at certain fruits, vegetables and bread (supermarkt things..).

So like this: Image - Cucumber - *fill in code here*

At the end, there is a check if you filled in the right code.
Only problem is is this:

**This works:**

index.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['komkommer'])){
        /* Include PHP scripts first */
        include_once 'phpscripts/plu.php';
        include_once 'phpscripts/groentestore.php';

        /* Call the check functions */
        if($komkommer != $plu_komkommer){
            echo '<p>Komkommer was niet juist! Jij voerde '.$komkommer.' in!   </p>';
        }
        if($rodekool != $plu_rodekool){
            echo '<p>Rode kool was niet juist! Jij voerde '.$rodekool.' in!</p>';
        }
        ...More of these if statements...
    }
    else {

    }
?>
```

groentestore.php:

```
<?php
    $komkommer = $_POST['komkommer'];
    $rodekool = $_POST['rodekool'];
    ...more of this...
?>
```

plu.php:

```
<?php
    $plu_komkommer = 232;
    $plu_rodekool = 236;
    ...more of this...
?>
```

**This doesn't work:**

index.html:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['komkommer'])){

        /* Include PHP scripts first */
        include_once 'phpscripts/plu.php';
        include_once 'phpscripts/groentestore.php';
        include_once 'phpscripts/functions.php';

        /* Call the check functions */
        groenteCheck();
    }
    else {

    }
?>
```

functions.php:

```
<?php
    function groenteCheck() {
        if($komkommer != $plu_komkommer){
            echo '<p>Komkommer was niet juist! Jij voerde '.$komkommer.' in!</p>';
        }
        if($rodekool != $plu_rodekool){
            echo '<p>Rode kool was niet juist! Jij voerde '.$rodekool.' in!</p>';
        }
        ...More of these is statements...
    }
?>
```

The second way, i'm getting these errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: plu_komkommer in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phpscripts\functions.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: komkommer in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phpscripts\functions.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: plu_rodekool in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phpscripts\functions.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: rodekool in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phpscripts\functions.php on line 6

I'm trying to get the second way to work, there are almost 50 of those if statements and i'd like to keep my index.php clean.
Any one knows what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you actually using the <?php ?> code inside the index.html page?

Comment: you need to check all the variables with `if(isset(plu_komkommer)) {  // your code here } `

Comment: Those variables are already there in the included files you need to make them global inside the function to use them or you can pass them as a parameter in the function when you call the function and you will not get these errors

Comment: you have to pass that all variable as parameters  to `groenteCheck();` this function.. like `groenteCheck($plu_komkommer,$rodekool,$plu_rodekool);` or defined them as global..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of how variable scoping works in PHP.

Inside your `groenteCheck()` function, you need a line at the top like:

```
function groenteCheck() {
    global $komkommer, $plu_komkommer ...

    // rest of function variables
}
```

More information on how scope works in PHP can be found [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: There are also other alternatives like referencing all the variables as `$GLOBALS['komkommer']`, etc. but I think this is ugly and makes it much harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

**Option-1:**

Declare them Global

```
<?php
    function groenteCheck() {
        global $komkommer, $plu_komkommer, $rodekool, $plu_rodekool;
        if($komkommer != $plu_komkommer){
            echo '<p>Komkommer was niet juist! Jij voerde '.$komkommer.' in!</p>';
        }
        if($rodekool != $plu_rodekool){
            echo '<p>Rode kool was niet juist! Jij voerde '.$rodekool.' in!</p>';
        }
        ...More of these is statements...
    }
?>
```

**Option-2:**

Pass them as parameter

```
<?php
    function groenteCheck($komkommer,$plu_komkommer, $rodekool, $plu_rodekool) {
        if($komkommer != $plu_komkommer){
            echo '<p>Komkommer was niet juist! Jij voerde '.$komkommer.' in!</p>';
        }
        if($rodekool != $plu_rodekool){
            echo '<p>Rode kool was niet juist! Jij voerde '.$rodekool.' in!</p>';
        }
        ...More of these is statements...
    }
?>
```

And call function like this

```
groenteCheck($komkommer,$plu_komkommer, $rodekool, $plu_rodekool);
```